# How do I convert this print statement into a data frame? Python NLP LSA topics

Tags: python, nlp, lsa

I need to add these LSA topics to each corresponding topic in my data frame. How can I get this print statement output in a data frame?

--> I am trying to get a data frame with the topic numbers and their corresponding keywords in a different column.

```
# most important words for each topic
vocab = vect.get_feature_names()

for i, comp in enumerate(lsa_model.components_):
    vocab_comp = zip(vocab, comp)
    sorted_words = sorted(vocab_comp, key= lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[:3]
    print("Topic "+str(i)+": ")
    for t in sorted_words:
        print(t[0],end=" ")
    print("\n")
```

topic 1:
xxx yyy zzz
.
.
.
Topic 8:
fddd dddd dsdsd

Topic 9:
akah ahkha ahkha

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the top of your work environment:

```
import pandas as pd

headings=['Name_of_Variable1','Name_of_Variable2'] # add more as needed
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=headings)
```

And, add the following line, or something similar, within your function after the `for t in sorted_words:`

`df = df.append(t,ignore_index=True)`

To look like:

```
for t in sorted_words:
    print(t[0],end=" ")
    df = df.append(t,ignore_index=True)
    print("\n")
```

Please use the following material to properly use the append function: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-append/

Comment: I tried that and this is what the error is -- TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: @AayushSethi, I think the issue is how the data in the function is coded. Before running the 'df = df.append(t,ignore_index=True)' line look at this page and format the data appropriately. If this works, please click the checkmark below the ranking for the question on the lefthand side. Thanks. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a data frame named `df` where the LSA topics are stored as integers under the column name `df['topics]`

You could do the following:

```
topic_map = {}
for i, comp in enumerate(lsa_model.components_):
    vocab_comp = zip(vocab, comp)
    sorted_words = sorted(vocab_comp, key= lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[:3]
    topic_map[i] = ' '.join(sorted_words)

df['topics'] = df['topics'].apply(lambda x: topic_map[x])
```

Comment: Not sure what the 'topics' refer to..!

Comment: The question asks "How to convert the print statemtent to a dataframe." 
The print statement, as shown, is using the top 3 words to make a textual topic name instead of the integer 0,1,2,.... topic names.
To add the LSA topics as text to a data frame row, you would at least need to know which integer topic it is, according to you LSA model.
Assuming that that integer topics are stored in a column named ["topics"], you can use the above code to turn those integer topic names into textual topic names similar to the print statement.